# Regex class :alpha: and :digit: contains space

Tags: regex, grep, whitespace, alpha, digits

I want to print with grep command, only the variable valid names in C that includes in some .txt file.

My result is this:

```
it1238@snf-622:~/templab$ grep '^[[:alpha:]]\([[:alpha:]]|_|[[:digit:]]\)\{0,31\}' textfile.txt
Feb 12, 1999
abc
alpha_beta
x
aQ
AS_xyz_XgZ
Jan 23, 2001
```

I can't understand why in results shows lines with whitespaces, such as Jan 23 and Feb 12.

OS: Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Grep version: grep (GNU grep) 2.10

Thanks anyway.

Comment: By default, `grep` prints the whole line where a match was found.  `Feb` matches your pattern, so the whole line `Feb 12, 1999` is printed.

Comment: Thanks both for your answers !!!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape `|` in BRE and also end the input pattern with anchor `$` to make sure full line is matched:

```
grep '^[[:alpha:]]\([[:alpha:]]\|_\|[[:digit:]]\)\{0,31\}$' file
abc
alpha_beta
x
aQ
AS_xyz_XgZ
```

However I suggest using [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and reduce your pattern to:

```
grep '^[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]_]\{0,31\}$' file
abc
alpha_beta
x
aQ
AS_xyz_XgZ
```